# What are validators in eclipse IDE?

Tags: eclipse, validation

In order to speed up the eclipse, we can disable one or more validators in Eclipse IDE. It actually speeds up the loading of eclipse.

**My question is not how to disable those validators.** I know how to do that.

My question is **What do those validators do?** Why do we need them? **What is the danger of disabling those validators?** If we do not want them, why does eclipse comes with them?

If we use a build tool like ant to build our project, does disabling those validators still have any effect?

Quoting the [offcial docs for juno](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.j2ee.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftjvalmanual.html)

> The validators used depend on the global and project validation settings. When you validate a project manually, the global settings are used unless both of the following are true:
>
> - The Allow projects to override these preference settings check box is    selected on the global validation preferences page.
> - The Override validation preferences check box is selected on the    project's validation preferences page.

What does that actually mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Validators are a feature of the Web Tools component of Eclipse. They provide a mechanism for checking the correctness of various file types (such as HTML, CSS, XML, JavaScript).

For file types such as Java the correctness of the file is determined when it is compiled, but there is no compiler for file types such as HTML so a different mechanism is need to check the files are correct. The validators provide this mechanism.

So if you turn of a validator you will longer get some messages about errors in files.

Comment: Your answer is clear. Better if you could answer to other questions as well. ' What is the danger of disabling those validators? '

Comment: I said at the end - if you turn them off you won't get messages about errors in files.